# Check if any checkbox in form is checked (MooTools)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox

I'm using a form with various checkbox groups and I would like the next button at the bottom of the page to appear only if any of the checkboxes is checked.

I found a working solution using jQuery here:

```
var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");

checkboxes.click(function() {
submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BPhZe/1937/

I'm looking for a way to do this with MooTools and I would prefer a solution where the button state is not "disabled" but hidden via CSS.

Answer (score 1):

MooTools has the property Element.checked to see whether the specified element is set to "checked" or not. MooTools also allows you to add ":checked" to your selector to get only the selected elements that match. This means you can do something like this to determine whether any checkboxes are checked:

```
if ($$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length > 0)
```

Or this to determine that *no* checkboxes are currently checked:

```
if ($$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length < 1)
```

Given the sample form you linked to, here is one way to do it:

```
$$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(checkboxInput) {
    checkboxInput.addEvent("click", function() {
        // show submit button if at least 1 checkbox is checked
        if (checkboxInput.checked) {
            $$("input[type=submit]").each(function(submitButton) {
                submitButton.removeProperty("disabled");
            });
        }
        // hide submit button if no checkboxes are checked
        if ($$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length < 1) {
            $$("input[type=submit]").each(function(submitButton) {
                submitButton.set("disabled", "disabled");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

If your submit button had an id attribute – say, id="formSubmitButton" – you could reference it that way and accomplish the same thing using slightly less code, instead of having to use $$("input[type=submit]").each(function(submitButton) { ... } :

```
$("formSubmitButton").removeProperty("disabled");
```

To change from disabling / re-enabling the button to showing / hiding the button, you could initiate the form with the button set with property  style="display:none;", and then call submitButton.removeProperty("style") when checkboxes are checked, and submitButton.setStyle("display", "none") when there are no longer any checked. Full code example for that version, using submit button with an ID:

```
$$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(checkboxInput) {
    checkboxInput.addEvent("click", function() {
        // show submit button if at least 1 checkbox is checked
        if (checkboxInput.checked) {
            $("formSubmitButton").removeProperty("style");
        }
        // hide submit button if no checkboxes are checked
        if ($$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length < 1) {
            $("formSubmitButton").setStyle("display", "none");
        }
    });
});
```